# Rotations in a multidimensional space using jordan canonical forms

Tags: linear-algebra

I asked a teacher if he could tell me some usefulness of a jordan canonical form, and his answer was:

"In a multidimensional space, you could use a JCF to define rotations for each of the planes."

So i'm interested if someone could give me more concrete ground for this idea... 
The matrix would be composed with blocks of rotations? How would the basis be? or what other important caracteristics should the space have?

Maybe a geometrical idea would be of some help aswell. Or a particular example..